# Windows.history.back() + location.reload() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've a probleme in my code. The aim is to complete a simple form, then you click on a submit button. It do an Ajax resquest to go in the method. On success in the ajax request, i use windows.history.back() to go to the previous page ans here i want to refresh this page, to refresh values which are modificated by the form ! Have you an idea about that ?

```
    $('#form_edit').submit(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#form_edit').attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === true) {
                    alert("Modification réussie !");
                    window.history.back();
                    location.reload(); <= on success i want to refresh previous page
                }
                else {
                    alert("Modification échouée !");
                }
            },
            error: function ()
            {
                alert("Modification échouée !");
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: try using location.href = document.referrer.

Comment: Redirect with a flag in the url that the previous page can recognise, then trigger a refresh if it's present on the previous page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will have already gone back before it executes the reload.

You would be better off to replace:

```
window.history.back();
location.reload();
```

with:

```
window.location.replace("pagehere.html");
```

Comment: i will try that, but it's not easy, in my url there is an ID. The value of this ID, change between the first page and the form page. I think that i can get it with localstorage

Comment: you can pass parameters with this: window.location.replace("pagehere.html?id=1");

Comment: The better option without extra coding: window.location.replace(document.referrer); Tested on chrome, safari, firefox, edge.

Answer (score 47):

`window.history.back();` Sometimes it's an issue with javascript compatibility with ajax call or design-related challenges.

I would use this below function for go back with the refresh.

```
function GoBackWithRefresh(event) {
    if ('referrer' in document) {
        window.location = document.referrer;
        /* OR */
        //location.replace(document.referrer);
    } else {
        window.history.back();
    }
}
```

In your html, use:

```
<a href="#" onclick="GoBackWithRefresh();return false;">BACK</a>`
```

For more customization you can use [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) plugins.

Comment: window.location = document.referrer;  did the job, thank you!

Comment: In your html, use <a href="#" onclick="GoBackWithRefresh();return false;">BACK</a>

Comment: `window.location = document.referrer` doesn't reload the page in current Firefox v70.

Answer (score 29):

**This is the correct answer. It will refresh the previous page.**

```
window.location=document.referrer;
```

Answer (score 14):

Try these ...

Option1

```
window.location=document.referrer;
```

Option2

```
window.location.reload(history.back());
```

Comment: i found window.location.reload(history.back()); doesn't work as expected - refreshes to current (not previous) page

Answer (score 8):

You can't do window.history.back(); and location.reload(); in the same function.

window.history.back() breaks the javascript flow and redirects to previous page, location.reload() is never processed.

location.reload() has to be called on the page you redirect to when using window.history.back().

I would used an url to redirect instead of history.back, that gives you both a redirect and refresh.

Answer (score 7):

I know this post is old but this can help.

```
window.location.replace(document.referrer);
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked reliably for me.

Answer (score 4):

After struggling with this for a few days, it turns out that you can't do a window.location.reload() after a `window.history.go(-2)`, because the code stops running after the `window.history.go(-2)`.  Also the html spec basically views a `history.go(-2)` to the the same as hitting the back button and should retrieve the page as it was instead of as it now may be.  There was some talk of setting caching headers in the webserver to turn off caching but I did not want to do this.

The solution for me was to use session storage to set a flag in the browser with `sessionStorage.setItem('refresh', 'true');` Then in the "theme" or the next page that needs to be refreshed do:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("refresh") == "true") { 
    sessionStorage.removeItem("refresh"); window.location.reload()
}
```

So basically tell it to reload in the sessionStorage then check for that at the top of the page that needs to be reloaded.

Hope this helps someone with this bit of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty old but I thought my answer would help someone as most of codes here refreshed current page not previous one

so you can't get back to previous page and refresh it at same time as JS will run the code that takes you back and stops (will not run refresh page part) so I found a way to combine both functions

```js
window.location.assign(window.history.back());
```

This basically will load a "new page" (so it will refresh it) but at same time it will load the previous page in browser history

Answer (score 0):

window.history.back() does not support reload or refresh of the page. But you can use following if you are okay with an extra refresh

```
window.history.back()
window.location.reload()
```

However a real complete solution would be as follows:
I wrote a service to keep track of previous page and then navigate to that page with reload:true

Here is how i did it.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('tryme5App')
    .factory('RouterTracker', function RouterTracker($rootScope) {
          var routeHistory = [];
          var service = {
            getRouteHistory: getRouteHistory
          };

          $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
              routeHistory = [];
              routeHistory.push({route: from, routeParams: fromParams});
          });

          function getRouteHistory() {
            return routeHistory;
          }

          return service;       
    });
```

Make sure you have included this js file from you index.html

```
<script src="scripts/components/util/route.service.js"></script>
```

Now from you stateprovider or controller you can access this service and navigate

```
var routeHistory = RouterTracker.getRouteHistory();    
console.log(routeHistory[0].route.name)
$state.go(routeHistory[0].route.name, null, { reload: true });
```

or alternatively even perform checks and conditional routing

```
var routeHistory = RouterTracker.getRouteHistory();    
console.log(routeHistory[0].route.name)
if(routeHistory[0].route.name == 'seat') {
      $state.go('seat', null, { reload: true });
} else {
      window.history.back()
}
```

Make sure you have added RouterTracker as an argument in your function
in my case it was :

```
.state('seat.new', {
                parent: 'seat',
                url: '/new',
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                },
                onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', 'RouterTracker', function($stateParams, $state, $uibModal, RouterTracker) {
  $uibModal.open({
      //....Open dialog.....
 }).result.then(function(result) {
            var routeHistory = RouterTracker.getRouteHistory();    
            console.log(routeHistory[0].route.name)
            $state.go(routeHistory[0].route.name, null, { reload: true });
 }, function() {
                    $state.go('^');
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Brandon Hoult answered of Dec 18, 2019 at 3:33**
I didn't get at at first but **YES, it works!** via session variable flag, but I'll say it it backwards

Set this in the page you want to be refreshed if user goes back to it with history back or browser back.

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("refresh") == "true") { 
    sessionStorage.removeItem("refresh"); window.location.reload()
}
```

Set this flag in the page you make changes like the shopping cart or the ajax mentioned that will change stuff, some setttings, classes, etc.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('refresh', 'true');
```

**My case:**

I hard code settings in a buy page while loading it, like prices and class of buy buttons: "add" or "in cart" icons. User adds an item to cart, then I add the product calling ajax and change that button's class to "in cart". If user wants to remove it from cart just clicks the cart icon and ajax again to remove it from cart and change class to "add".

**Problem:**

User goes to cart page itself, see the products and decide to go back and page show old buttons icons because is history (first loaded page, not changed one) so need to reload the show updated info.

**Solution above does:**

Buy page will reload if user goes to cart and back since cart page set a session variable "refresh" and buy page checks if "refresh" = true, set refresh it to false (so only cart page can set refresh to true and refresh the page.

*Session variable "refresh" is a name so you can call it whatever else so you can use as many different flags as you want.*

Answer (score 0):

step 1: save the referrer URL in the local cache on load functions.

```
$(function () {
  let refUrl = document.referrer;
  let origin = location.origin;   
  if (refUrl.replace(origin, '') !== location.pathname) {
    localStorage.setItem("history", refUrl.replace(origin, ''));
  }
});
```

step 2: redirect the page to the referrer URL on link click.

```
$('body').on('click', '.lnkRurl', function () {
  location.href = localStorage.getItem('history');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to disable http cache from server like this(php code).

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but the code never changes. So I'd like to contribute with a solution.

Put this on the page you want to refresh itself when you go back.

```html
<!-- Refresh with the new changes made -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.addEventListener("pageshow", function (event) {
    var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
    if (perfEntries[0].type === "back_forward") {
      location.reload(true);
    }
  });
</script>
```